# How to find out which folder Tomcat is installed by brew on MacOS?

Tags: tomcat, homebrew

I am learning JSP programing which requires Tomcat. I followed [some tutorials](https://wolfpaulus.com/journal/mac/tomcat8/) but failed to install successfully(Probably some step is not clear match to my situation)

Then I found out you can install easily by this command line:

```
brew install tomcat
```

It looks install is successful,

[image]

My challenge is after install, I don't know where it is on my hard drive. Therefore, can't configure it in IntelliJ.

[image]

My question is:

How do I find out where Tomcat is installed by brew on MacOS?

Thanks!

Comment: I know the answer has been given, but here's the way I found out: after `brew install tomcat` I did `catalina version` and found that `CATALINA_HOME` was set to `/usr/local/Cellar/tomcat/<tomcat-version>/libexec`.

Answer (score 150):

```
brew ls tomcat
```

This command will show the directory of brew package.

Comment: It was `brew ls tomcat@8` in my case. Therefore, the `Tomcat Home: /usr/local/opt/tomcat@8/libexec/`

Answer (score 85):

In case someone else stumbles upon this: I had to select

```
/usr/local/Cellar/tomcat/<tomcat-version>/libexec
```

as Tomcat Home in IntelliJ.

Answer (score 25):

Although the answer of cbst is working. I think it is better to choose the dynamic path to tomcat which is located in

```
/usr/local/opt/tomcat
```

The configuration that I would suggest is the following two Tomcat application servers:

## Configuration

### Application Server 01

```
Name: Tomcat latest
Tomcat Home: /usr/local/opt/tomcat/libexec
```

### Application Server 02

```
Name: Tomcat X.Y
Tomcat Home: /usr/local/opt/tomcat@X.Y/libexec
```

## Advantage

When you upgrade tomcat using

```
brew upgrade
```

Your tomcat servers are likely to keep working. If the latest version is a major release your specific version **Tomcat X.Y** will not work anymore, which is good as you have confidence you are running a correct tomcat version. To keep working with a specific tomcat version use

```
brew install tomcat@X
```

Comment: you may need to use `/usr/local/opt/tomcat@8/libexec` in order to get this to work on intellij

Answer (score 8):

It's very simple:

```
$ catalina home
```

And you'll probably get: `/usr/local/Cellar/tomcat/<VERSION_NUMBER/libexec` if you installed tomcat via homebrew.

Answer (score 6):

You should use:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/tomcat@8/<tomcat version>/libexec/
```

Answer (score 4):

**find / -name "webapps"**

run the above command on your terminal of mac. And during the search, it should list out the path of your tomcat directory. 
in my case, it was:

/Users/jayantagarwal/Documents/apache-tomcat-9.0.14/webapps

Answer (score 3):

If installed using brew on Mac M1chip the location of tomcat will be

```
/opt/homebrew/etc/tomcat
```

Answer (score 2):

## The libraries, tools which are installed through brew.sh are stored in

```
/usr/local/Cellar
```

- in your case you can find tomcat in:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/tomcat
```